# How to give tooltip to CommandItems[save changes button, cancel changes button] of Telerik Radgrid in batch edit mode?

Tags: asp.net, batch-file, telerik, tooltip, radgrid

I am using a telerik RadGrid in batch edit mode. Kindly Suggest a way to give tool tip to the default buttons like "Save Changes" button, "Cancel Changes button" of RadGrid in batch edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

They have titles by default: http://screencast.com/t/mdCTqocCK

Anyway, you can make your own custom header with your own controls with the desired tooltips: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/commanditem/command-item-template#custom-commanditemtemplate-for-batch-edit-mode

Before anyone reports this for links only - here is the code snippet from the article

```
<telerik:RadGrid RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadGrid1" GridLines="None" runat="server" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True"
                 AllowAutomaticInserts="True" PageSize="10" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" AllowPaging="True"
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom" DataKeyNames="ProductID"
                     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" HorizontalAlign="NotSet" EditMode="Batch" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <CommandItemTemplate>
            <telerik:RadPushButton runat="server" ID="AddNewRecordButton" OnClientClicked="addRecordToGrid" AutoPostBack="false" Text="Add new record" ToolTip="Add new record">
                <Icon CssClass="rgAddIcon" />
            </telerik:RadPushButton>
            <telerik:RadPushButton runat="server" ID="SaveChangesButton" OnClientClicked="saveChangesToGrid" AutoPostBack="false" Text="Save changes" ToolTip="Save changes">
                <Icon CssClass="rgSaveIcon" />
            </telerik:RadPushButton>
            <telerik:RadPushButton runat="server" ID="CancelChangesButton" OnClientClicked="cancelChangesToGrid" AutoPostBack="false" Text="Cancel changes" ToolTip="Cancel changes">
                <Icon CssClass="rgCancelIcon" />
            </telerik:RadPushButton>
            <telerik:RadPushButton runat="server" ID="RefreshButton" OnClientClicked="refreshGrid" AutoPostBack="false" Text="Refresh" ToolTip="Refresh">
                <Icon CssClass="rgRefreshIcon" />
            </telerik:RadPushButton>
        </CommandItemTemplate>
        <BatchEditingSettings EditType="Cell" />
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

and the sample scripts

```
function addRecordToGrid() {
    var grid = $find('<%=RadGrid1.ClientID%>');
    grid.get_batchEditingManager().addNewRecord(grid.get_masterTableView());
    return false;
}
function saveChangesToGrid() {
    var grid = $find('<%=RadGrid1.ClientID%>');
    grid.get_batchEditingManager().saveChanges(grid.get_masterTableView());
    return false;
}
function cancelChangesToGrid() {
    var grid = $find('<%=RadGrid1.ClientID%>');
    grid.get_batchEditingManager().cancelChanges(grid.get_masterTableView());
    return false;
}
function refreshGrid() {
    var grid = $find('<%=RadGrid1.ClientID%>');
    grid.get_masterTableView().rebind();
}
```